# Is there any difference between using a Raw layer, and simply attaching a string to a packet?

Tags: python, scapy

Is there any difference between explicitly using `Raw`, and simply using a string/bytes object in its place? Or in other words, is there any difference between these two lines?

```
p1 = ARP(pdst="192.168.72.102") / "Some Test Data"
p2 = ARP(pdst="192.168.72.102") / Raw(load="Some Test Data")
```

They appear to act identically when inspecting the results in Wireshark and when looking at the produced scapy packet objects, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `conf.raw_layer` hasn't been altered, they are the same.

If you check the implementation of `Packet.__div__` (`/`; the separator used to "glue" layers together), it defers to `Raw` when a `str` or `bytes` object is given:

```py
def __div__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Packet):
        cloneA = self.copy()
        cloneB = other.copy()
        cloneA.add_payload(cloneB)
        return cloneA
    elif isinstance(other, (bytes, str)):
        return self / conf.raw_layer(load=other)
    else:
        return other.__rdiv__(self)
```

And `conf.raw_layer` is later defined as `conf.raw_layer = Raw`

Comment: In some very specific cases you would change `conf.raw_layer` to something else, because it is also what a packet becomes if dissection fails. But for the most part, yeah